# Same Layout - Unique Class Names with October CMS

Tags: octobercms

I am new to October CMS and am wondering how to create unique class names on different pages when using the same layout.  For instance, the home page may be `<html class="home">` whereas the blog page may be `<html class="blog">` and so on.

Any recommendations on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="page-{{ this.page.id }} layout-{{ this.layout.id }}">
```

You can access the current page object via `this.page` and it returns the object Cms\Classes\Page. This object can also be accessed in the PHP code. `this.page` has the following properties: layout, id, title and etc. More information you can find [here](http://octobercms.com/docs/markup/this-page).

Comment: Thanks; but it needed to be edited in (using the [edit] button). I've done it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way - create partial and include in pages:

pages/home.htm

```
title = "home"
url = "/home"
layout = "mylayout"
==
<?php
    function onStart() 
    {
        $this['class'] = 'home';
    }
?>
==
{% partial mypage.htm %}
```

pages/blog.htm

```
title = "blog"
url = "/blog"
layout = "mylayout"
==
<?php
    function onStart() 
    {
        $this['class'] = 'blog';
    }
?>
==
{% partial mypage.htm %}
```

and in partials/mypage.htm

```
<html class="{{ class }}">
```